# Prophet Package Seasonality

Tags: r, time-series, facebook-prophet

I am trying to extract the seasonality from the Prophet package from Facebook in R.

The code is as follows:

```
library('prophet')
df <- data.frame(ds=data$DATE,y=data$REVENUE)
m <- prophet(df, daily.seasonality = TRUE)
```

Where m is a prophet list class

I am able to extract the trend and holidays from the package, but have been unsuccessful extracting the seasonalities so far.

I am however able to plot the seasonalities using:

```
future <- make_future_dataframe(m, periods = 20, freq = 'day')
forecast <- predict(m, future)
prophet_plot_components(m, forecast)
```

This gives the following plot:
Seasonalities and trend using the prophet package:

[image]

How can I get the values for 'Day of year' and 'Day of weak' from these plots?

Thank you for your help!

Here is a bit of data if someone wants to tinker around:

```
structure(list(ds = c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", "2019-01-04", "2019-01-05"), y = c(0.0586635581195361, 0.14179154500982, 0.154505062394315, 0.138202481405581, 0.0992742352440193)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: structure(list(ds = c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", 
"2019-01-04", "2019-01-05"), y = c(0.0586635581195361, 0.14179154500982, 
0.154505062394315, 0.138202481405581, 0.0992742352440193)), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Edit this to be included in your question please. Dput can be easily lost in comments if there is an extended conversation here.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. The forecast dataframe created after by prediction on the original data, has multiple attributes including trend and seasonality.

To extract daily seasonality you can use,

```
daily <- forecast$daily
```

Similarly if there are other type of seasonality they're stored as `monthly`, `yearly` etc. You can also specify custom seasonalities in prophet as mentioned [here](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/seasonality,_holiday_effects,_and_regressors.html#specifying-custom-seasonalities)